# How to map over an ADT's constructor's arguments?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type (shown below in GADT form):

```
data Test a where
  C1 :: Int -> a -> Test a
  C2 :: Test a -> Test a -> a -> Test a
  C3 :: Test a -> a -> Test a
  ...
```

What I want to do, is to be able to apply some function `Monoid m => Test a -> m` generically to any given instance of `Test a` in the constructor, then `mappend` it all.

So for example, given f:

```
f :: Test a -> [Int]
f (C1 n _) = [n]
f _        = []
```

I'd like some function g that can map this over each constructor argument like so:

```
g :: Monoid m => (Test a -> m) -> Test a -> m
g f v@(C1 Int _) = f v
g f (C2 x y _)   = f x `mappend` f y
g f (C3 x _)     = f x
...
```

Except that I don't want to write `g`, I want to write a generic version of `g`, that can do this for any supported data type (I'm thinking GHC.Generics might be a good fit for this, but haven't been able to get the types right).
i.e. I'd like to separate the actual mechanics of traversing my data structure (the repeating application of `f` with a `mappend` based fold) from the *interesting* bits (the terminal case of `C1` in `g` above)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it supposed to apply `f` to *only* values made with the the `C1` constructor?  Why not the `C2` or `C3` constructor?  is it only for constructors with no recursive argument?  If there was a `C4 Int (Test a)` constructor or a `C5 Int` constructor, what would happen?

Comment: No, `f` can pick which `Test a` parts it wants, so given the definition of `f` as given in the question, I would want `g` to return `f r` for `C4 i r` and `[]` (or mempty) for `C5 i`. Hope that clarifies the question.Your comment actually made me realize it might be easier for `f` to call a function to do the fold than having `g` call `f` instead.

Comment: GHC.Generics is a good bet, it can be hard to use if you've never used it before.  Have you read [the paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2003/01/hmap.pdf)? -- when I read the paper it stopped being a dark incantation and started being a useful tool, imagine that!

Answer (score 1):

Practically, I'd look a bit deeper into GHC.Generics, and definitely read [the SYB paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2003/01/hmap.pdf) if you haven't.

I'll outline another approach here which is to use fixpoint types, which is a pretty slick fit for this problem.

```
newtype Mu f = Roll { unroll :: f (Mu f) }

-- Replace all recursive constructors with r.
-- If any of them are nonregular (e.g. C3 :: Test Int -> Test a)
-- then this approach gets quite a bit more complicated, so I hope not.
data TestF a r where
  C1 :: Int -> a -> TestF a r
  C2 :: r -> r -> a -> TestF a r
  ...

-- This will take care of finding the recursive constructors
deriving instance Foldable (TestF a) 

-- This is your actual type (might want to wrap it in a newtype)
type Test a = Mu (TestF a)

foldMapRec :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => (Mu f -> m) -> Mu f -> m
foldMapRec f (Roll a) = foldMap f a
```

In practice I haven't actually gotten much use out of fixpoint types, they always seem to be more hassle than they're worth.  But with `PatternSynonyms` now implemented I think it's somewhat nicer.  Anyway, just wanted to show you this for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is more or less exactly what the function `composFold` does as described in the paper ["A pattern for almost compositional functions"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/alumni/bringert/publ/composOp-jfp/composOp-jfp.pdf) (Section 3).

The [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) package claims to have a [compatibility layer for compos-like operations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Compos.html), with

```
composOpMonoid :: (Uniplate a, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> a -> m
```

corresponding to the operation you seem to be looking for.